# command ps with option -l

Tags: linux, terminal, fedora, ps

I'm working on linux terminal,Fedora. And I want to find number of processes that have executed fork() call. I used first command ps -elf to list all processes with all possible details.

I want to know what does the first column from the left "F" refers to? maybe number of children for a parent?

p.s: manual doesn't mention the details of option -l.

[image]

Comment: [You should read this](http://www.computerhope.com/unix/ups.htm)

Comment: @Michi I did, thnx:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

actually, the man gives the answer:

`f          F        flags associated with the process, see the PROCESS FLAGS section. (alias flag, flags).`

then if you look at the `PROCESS FLAGS` section, you get:

`PROCESS FLAGS
The sum of these values is displayed in the "F" column, which is provided by the flags output specifier.
1    forked but didn't exec
4    used super-user privileges`

which will probably explain why you get only 0, 1, 4 or 5 as values in this column,

Answer (score 0):

It's the option for how it will display the output of ps command.

```
Usage:
 ps [options]

 Try 'ps --help <simple|list|output|threads|misc|all>'
  or 'ps --help <s|l|o|t|m|a>'
 for additional help text.

For more details see ps(1).
```

In case ps -l, it will display the below detail,

```
Usage:
 ps [options]

Selection by list:
 -C <command>         command name
 -G, --Group <gid>    real group id or name
 -g, --group <group>  session or effective group name
 -p, --pid <pid>      process id
     --ppid <pid>     select by parent process id
 -s, --sid <session>  session id
 -t, t, --tty <tty>   terminal
 -u, U, --user <uid>  effective user id or name
 -U, --User <uid>     real user id or name

  selection <arguments> take either:
    comma-separated list e.g. '-u root,nobody' or
    blank-separated list e.g. '-p 123 4567'

For more details see ps(1).
```

Comment: -l is often used with y like **-yl**, but using only **-l** is more powerful because there are more infos to be read, by the way there is **ps l** too wich ignores the **S** (STAT col).

Comment: @Michi I am using ubuntu , My linux distro having ps -l option, Could you please explain what I need to learn?

Comment: did i sad that you need to learn something? :)

Comment: @Michi No , But I thought so :-D